# can't map array after actually printing the array inside passed data

Tags: reactjs

I am passing data to presentations (stateless) class, the data is passed and I can print the array of prices passed inside it, however when I try to map this array I get an error ('Cannot read property 'map' of undefined')

[The codesandbox code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/013jrzp5wv)

```
const CoinCharts = ({prices}) => (
      <div className='section'>
        // this console.log get an array printed
    {console.log( ( prices.Data ) )}


    {prices.Data.map( (price) => 
     <div> something here </div>
    )}
)
```

The index.js just passed the data like this

```
 <div className='column'> <CoinCharts prices={this.state.prices} /> </div>
```

The data passes ok and prints ok, but doesn't map

Comment: what does the console log print, is it an array, an obj? What does the map function print - nothing at all? Any errors in the console?

Comment: The error I get is 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined', the console logs the prices of passed data

Comment: so is `prices.Data` an array? Try logging `Array.isArray(prices.Data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because at the first render there's nothing in prices.Data. You're grabbing the data with a promise from Axios. So you have to check for the data to actually be there otherwise you'll get this error. You can do that in many ways but one is this:

```
const CoinCharts = ({prices}) => (
      <div className='section'>
        // this console.log get an array printed
    {console.log( ( prices.Data ) )}


     { prices.Data ? prices.Data.map( (price, key) =>
      <div key={key} >Something here</div> 
     ) : null }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that delay in receiving data, I can use your method with isLoading too :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change this line:

```
prices: response.data
```

to this one

```
prices: response.data.Data
```

that should do the job.